# Toast in an AlertDialog in a try/catch

Tags: android, sqlite, try-catch, toast, android-alertdialog

I am trying to have an error message when the use enters a number for an item that cannot be deleted in the database. I have gotten it so the user can delete an item from the database and I think used the try catch to avoid a run time error if the number does not exist.  What I am trying to do is have a toast pop up when the user enter an invalid number.  I have already looked at other similar postings on stack and have not have any luck. Here is my code.  If you need me to post more code let me know.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    try {
        String id=idNum.getText().toString();
        long primaryId=Long.parseLong(id);

        info.open();
        info.deleteInspection(primaryId);
        info.close();
        dbInfo();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can give `info.deleteInspection(primaryId);` a return value and show the toast when it returns something meaning that the number does not exist. Catching exceptions isn't a rly clean approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `deleteInspection()` method return a boolean value, telling wether or not a given id was deleted. Then check for it in your onClick method:

```
boolean result = info.deleteInspection(primaryId);
if(!result) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am having trouble figuring out how to turn my delete statement into a boolean.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Aaron The SQLiteDatabase object has a `delete()` method, it returns the number of rows affected (0 or 1 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

It's not about try/catch here, that you want to post "number not found"

the thing you need is the return the result from your Database that it found this id to delete or not

As Soren.Qvist said.

you need to return some value from your Database to  your code (maybe -1, false, etc.) and check at it